# rosmsg md5 Cannot locate message

Tags: ros, md5, rosmsg

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On a fresh install of Fuerte on Oneiric (desktop-full installed from binary packages)
the command rosmsg md5 does not appear to work:

```
$ rosmsg md5 std_msgs/String 
Cannot locate [std_msgs/String]
```

while rosmsg show works as expected:

```
$ rosmsg show std_msgs/String
string data
```

Any suggestion about what might be causing the problem or on how to investigate the issue further is much appreciated.

Filed as ticket [#3961](https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3961)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33477/rosmsg-md5-cannot-locate-message/) by [renzodenardi](https://answers.ros.org/users/2291/renzodenardi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 51 on 2012-05-07

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2012-05-07**:
I have a suspicion that this is a bug. rosmsg show std_msgs/String works for me, but not md5 (same goes with a few other message types I've tried).

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2012-05-08**:
I can confirm this too. You should file a ticket.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-05-09**:
Doesn't work on OSX either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like [patch was applied](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/commit/a6b82300d3604d71b9613c1d048c5374979275b3) right away.

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2013-01-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0